# Javascript Convert an Object to a URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an object which looks something like this:

```
activeFilters: {
    category: {
        '1': 'View All',
        '2': ' Flats'
    },
    brand: {
        '1': 'Fits'
    }
}
```

I want to map through the object and use these as URL parameters. The end result will look something like this:

`https://api.websiteurl.com/products?category=1,2&brand=1`

I am using react and I can use lodash. Wanted help on whats the best way to achieve this

Comment: You don't need lodash nor React for that.

Comment: Are `category` and `brand` _really_ `object` values and not Arrays? It's unusual to have numeric property keys in `object` values.

Comment: `https://api.websiteurl.com/products&category=1,2&brand=1` <-- This is an invalid URI, you're missing the querystring `?` character.

Comment: I know, I wanted to let everyone know what I am using and If we can produce a more readable and easy solution then it would be best

Comment: @Dai yes it's a redux object where keys represent the ids. I update it using something like this: `{...state.filters, [action.id]: [action.name]}`

Comment: @Dai thankyou for pointing it out. I've added the ? in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to achieve the desired result

```js
const filters = {
  activeFilters: {
    category: {
      "1": "View All",
      "2": " Flats",
    },
    brand: {
      "1": "Fits",
    },
  },
};

const queryString = Object.entries(filters.activeFilters)
  .map(([k, v]) => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(Object.keys(v))}`)
  .join("&");

const url = "https://api.websiteurl.com/products";

// Thanks Dai for this suggestion to encode the path.
const result = `${url}?${queryString}`;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Don't forget to encode the querystring parameters, otherwise a value with `=` or `&` in it will break everything.

Comment: Ideally you should `encodeURIComponent` the values although in this example they are just numbers.

Comment: Also your code is also missing the `?` character.

Comment: Your code doesn't include `filters.brand` btw.

Comment: @decpk The `?` is required for query-strings, otherwise it's an invalid URI. I believe the OP made a typo.

Comment: @Dai thankyou for mentioning that. I do need the ?

Comment: You're using `encodeURIComponent` incorrectly. You need to use `encodeURIComponent` to encode each querystring name and value separately. But you shouldn't need to use `encodeURIComponent` if you use `URLSearchParams` instead.

Comment: @Dai I've updated the code please have a look.

Comment: @decpk You still need to change `const result = \`${url}&${path}\`;` to `const result = \`${url}?${path}\`;`. Also, the query-string is not the "path". Rename your `path` variable to `qs`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const activeFilters = {category: {'1': 'View All','2': ' Flats'},brand: {'1': 'Fits'}}

const queryParams = Object.entries(activeFilters).map((query) => {
  //Join all query keys values with ','
  const values = Object.keys(query[1]).map((val) => val).join(',');
  //add these values to name of the query
  return query[0]+'='+values;
}).join('&'); //join final result with '&'

console.log(queryParams)
url = 'https://google.com?'+queryParams;
console.log(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) package to stringify the data to URL query parameters. But first, we need to convert the data like below:

```js
qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'comma' })
// 'a=b,c'
```

The encoding can be disabled by setting the `encode` option to `false`.

E.g.

```js
var qs = require("qs")

const activeFilters =  {
    category: {
        '1': 'View All',
        '2': ' Flats'
    },
    brand: {
        '1': 'Fits'
    }
}

const r = Object.keys(activeFilters).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur] = Object.keys(activeFilters[cur]);
  return acc;
}, {})

const search = qs.stringify(r, {arrayFormat: 'comma', encode: false})
console.log(search)
// "category=1,2&brand=1"
console.log(`https://api.websiteurl.com/products?${search}`) 
// "https://api.websiteurl.com/products?category=1,2&brand=1"
```

[RunKit](https://runkit.com/embed/1ojf4ka3ko2a)

Comment: What does `qs` do that the built-in `URLSearchParams` object doesn't? I don't think we should be _perpetuating_ the JS package mess situation we're in right now: in-box solutions should be preferred imo.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```js
const objectToParams = (object) => {
  if (object && Object.keys(object).length > 0) {
    const resultArr = [];
    Object.keys(object).map((key) => {
      const keys = Object.keys(object[key]).join(",");
      resultArr.push(`${key}=${keys}`);
    });
    return resultArr.join("&");
  }
};

const activeFilters = {
    category: {
        '1': 'View All',
        '2': ' Flats'
    },
    brand: {
        '1': 'Fits'
    }
}

const url = `https:google.com/products?`;
const result = `${url}${encodeURIComponent(objectToParams(activeFilters))}`;

console.log("url is: ", result)
```

Comment: You aren't URI-encoding parameter names and values. You're missing the `?` separator.

Comment: added `?` operator.

Comment: Thank you @Dai. Added URI-encoding as well.

Comment: You're using `encodeURIComponent` incorrectly.